# GCP Cloud Router Stackdriver metrics not available

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-stackdriver

Has anyone tried monitoring GCP Cloud Routers with stackdriver? According to [their metrics page](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-router) there are several metrics that should be available, however, the resource explorer shows no indication.

I have two cloud routers, with interfaces and peers.

Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the metrics you mentioned are available in Stackdriver monitoring for Cloud routers.

You should be able to see those metrics published by the Cloud routers by following this [link1](https://cloud.google.com/router/docs/how-to/viewing-metrics#viewing_metrics_via_the_api) .

If you are not able to see the Cloud routers metrics, there could be an internal issue in your project that prevents you to add Cloud router metrics to a dashboard.

In this case, I suggest that you open a public issue tracker [PIT](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers), 
explaining briefly your concern and providing the HAR logs when trying to create a dashboard with Cloud routers metrics.

Chrome has a built-in tool that outputs these headers as HAR files. To gather these logs, do the following in an incognito window:

1. Click the menu icon in the top-right. This is the icon with three horizontal lines.
2. Choose 'More tools'->'Developer tools' to bring up the console.
3. Select 'Network'.
4. Ensure the box labeled 'Preserve log' is checked.
5. You will see a small red circle in the top-left of the console, indicating that it is recording. If the circle is black, click on it to begin recording.
6. Reproduce the issue (go to the Stackdriver Monitoring Console and reproduce the issue). You'll begin to see data collecting in the console window.
7. Click the red circle to stop recording.
8. Right-click in the console window and select 'Save as HAR with Content' to download the .har data file.

You should close the session that the HAR file belongs to. You can do this by signing out of your Google account. You should also remove any sensitive information like cookies and tokens in the HAR file by using the HAR sanitizer tool for example [1](https://github.com/google/har-sanitizer).
I hope this helps.